# Error while running the OCR azure cognitive services - key error

Tags: python, azure, opencv, ocr, keyerror

I am using the following code to perform ocr on receipts.

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxx\\Documents\\ocr\\xxx.json")
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
#print(data)

import os
import azure.ai.vision as sdk

service_options = sdk.VisionServiceOptions(os.environ["VISION_ENDPOINT"],
                                           os.environ["VISION_KEY"])

vision_source = sdk.VisionSource(
    url="https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/media/quickstarts/presentation.png")

analysis_options = sdk.ImageAnalysisOptions()

analysis_options.features = (
    sdk.ImageAnalysisFeature.CAPTION |
    sdk.ImageAnalysisFeature.TEXT
)

analysis_options.language = "en"

analysis_options.gender_neutral_caption = True

image_analyzer = sdk.ImageAnalyzer(service_options, vision_source, analysis_options)

result = image_analyzer.analyze()

if result.reason == sdk.ImageAnalysisResultReason.ANALYZED:

    if result.caption is not None:
        print(" Caption:")
        print("   '{}', Confidence {:.4f}".format(result.caption.content, result.caption.confidence))

    if result.text is not None:
        print(" Text:")
        for line in result.text.lines:
            points_string = "{" + ", ".join([str(int(point)) for point in line.bounding_polygon]) + "}"
            print("   Line: '{}', Bounding polygon {}".format(line.content, points_string))
            for word in line.words:
                points_string = "{" + ", ".join([str(int(point)) for point in word.bounding_polygon]) + "}"
                print("     Word: '{}', Bounding polygon {}, Confidence {:.4f}"
                      .format(word.content, points_string, word.confidence))

else:

    error_details = sdk.ImageAnalysisErrorDetails.from_result(result)
    print(" Analysis failed.")
    print("   Error reason: {}".format(error_details.reason))
    print("   Error code: {}".format(error_details.error_code))
    print("   Error message: {}".format(error_details.message))
```

However upon running the above code with the command line:
python sample.py -k "my end_point" -e "my subscription key"
The following error is returned.
KeyError: 'VISION_ENDPOINT'
Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

The error message `KeyError: 'VISION_ENDPOINT'` indicates that the environment variable `VISION_ENDPOINT` is not found.

To fix this, you can first assign the environment variable values for endpoint and key.

```py
import os
os.environ["VISION_ENDPOINT"] = "your_endpoint"
os.environ["VISION_KEY"] = "your_key"
```

However, it seems you're running the script from the command line with arguments `-k` and `-e` and for that you need to make sure these arguments are correctly parsed and used in your script. The provided code snippet doesn't show how these arguments are handled.

Below is the updated code with command line arguments for the endpoint and key:

```py
import os
import argparse
import azure.ai.vision as sdk

# Parse command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Perform OCR on receipts.')
parser.add_argument('-k', '--key', help='Your subscription key', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-e', '--endpoint', help='Your endpoint', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

service_options = sdk.VisionServiceOptions(args.endpoint, args.key)

vision_source = sdk.VisionSource(
    url="https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/media/quickstarts/presentation.png")

analysis_options = sdk.ImageAnalysisOptions()

analysis_options.features = (
    sdk.ImageAnalysisFeature.CAPTION |
    sdk.ImageAnalysisFeature.TEXT
)

analysis_options.language = "en"

analysis_options.gender_neutral_caption = True

image_analyzer = sdk.ImageAnalyzer(service_options, vision_source, analysis_options)

result = image_analyzer.analyze()

if result.reason == sdk.ImageAnalysisResultReason.ANALYZED:

    if result.caption is not None:
        print(" Caption:")
        print("   '{}', Confidence {:.4f}".format(result.caption.content, result.caption.confidence))

    if result.text is not None:
        print(" Text:")
        for line in result.text.lines:
            points_string = "{" + ", ".join([str(int(point)) for point in line.bounding_polygon]) + "}"
            print("   Line: '{}', Bounding polygon {}".format(line.content, points_string))
            for word in line.words:
                points_string = "{" + ", ".join([str(int(point)) for point in word.bounding_polygon]) + "}"
                print("     Word: '{}', Bounding polygon {}, Confidence {:.4f}"
                      .format(word.content, points_string, word.confidence))

else:

    error_details = sdk.ImageAnalysisErrorDetails.from_result(result)
    print(" Analysis failed.")
    print("   Error reason: {}".format(error_details.reason))
    print("   Error code: {}".format(error_details.error_code))
    print("   Error message: {}".format(error_details.message))
```